# Show zero value in baidu echarts heatmap

Tags: javascript, echarts

As this [demo](http://echarts.baidu.com/demo.html#heatmap-cartesian) shows, 0 value is not displayed no matter if I set series.label.normal.show true or false. What I want to do is, even the value is 0, it should be displayed as well in the cell of the heatmap.

I tried to find something from the API doc but did not find any useful configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = data.map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
});
```

this should be changed to

```
data = data.map(function (item) {
    return [item[1], item[0], item[2]];
});
```